# How to replace URLs from the packets that are transferred through a proxy?

Tags: python, http, proxy

I am writing code for my own Proxy server in python. The code that transfers packets from client and target server is as follows :

```
def _read_write(self):
        if self.target:
            pass
        else:
            domain, port = self.get_target_host()
            self._connect_target(domain, port)

        self.target.send(self.headers)

        maxtimeout = self.timeout / 3
        inputs = [self.client, self.target]
        count = 0
        try:

            while 1:
                count += 1
                (recv, send, err) = select.select(inputs, [], inputs)

                if err:
                    break

                if recv:
                    for in_ in recv:
                        data = in_.recv(BUFFLEN)

                        if in_ is self.client:
                            out = self.target
                        else:
                            out = self.client

                        if data:
                            out.send(data)
                            count = 0
                if count == maxtimeout:
                    break
        except select.error:
            print >> sys.stderr, "Error : Internal queue error\n", "Reason : Unknown"
```

Now since each packet is individually transferred from the client to the server, I want to intercept the data being transferred and replace the URLs of resources such as images, css, etc. with some new URLs with the closest server from the client. Is this the right way to do it ? I think I will get into a problem if the URL is separated by the packets.

Answer (score 0):

Right - it would be difficult to do this on the packet level. What might be easier would be to build the entire data in the proxy first, then do your processing, then send the data to the client.

Comment: First I had done that but something is going wrong. The script takes a lot of time to execute. What I want to do is replace the URL with a CDN URL. I am not able to find any information about how to develop CDN.